# Chinese Character Issue in AJAX with C# & Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am getting Ajax Error with chinese character can anyone share fix?

**Error**
[image]

**Jquery**

```
var jqxhr = $.post("Handler1.ashx", function () {
    alert("success");
}).fail(function (data) {
    alert("error");
});
```

**C#**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var ticketResponse = new TicketResponse();
            ticketResponse.AddedCount = 23;

            // All tickets were available and were added to the cart
            ticketResponse.Success = true;
            ticketResponse.SuccessItems = new List<SuccessfullItem>
                                              {
                                                  new SuccessfullItem()
                                                      {

                                                          OrderItemId = 1,
                                                          Title = "【桃姐與我】舞台劇（粵語）粵語）"
                                                      }
                                              };


            var output = Serializer.Serialize(ticketResponse);
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", output.Length.ToString());
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "text");
            context.Response.Write(output);
            context.Response.Flush();
            context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you check Firebug? Also, are you getting an exception in your method or just an error on the other end?

Comment: do u have the same issue when u remove the spaces, square and round brackets?

Comment: yes same error with one charachter even "桃"

Comment: You probably ought to specify a proper *charset* attribute on your Content-Type header. e.g. `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution .... It is not working with Generic Handler but it works fine with webservice without any problem.

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]     
    public Handler1.TicketResponse HelloWorld()
    {
        var ticketResponse = new Handler1.TicketResponse();
        ticketResponse.AddedCount = 23;

        // All tickets were available and were added to the cart
        ticketResponse.Success = true;
        ticketResponse.SuccessItems = new List<Handler1.SuccessfullItem>
                                          {
                                              new Handler1.SuccessfullItem()
                                                  {

                                                      OrderItemId = 1,
                                                      Title = "【桃姐與我】舞台劇（粵語）粵語）"
                                                  }
                                          };

        return ticketResponse;
    }
```